# View PDF files via PDFBox-android

Tags: android, pdfbox

I need to view PDF files (just view, nothing more) on my Android application, and i've been asked to use [pdfbox for android](https://github.com/Birdbrain2/PdfBox-Android).

What is the simplest way to view PDF files via this library? i don't seem to find an example for doing that

Comment: Unexplained down-votes... sure makes me want to be a part of this community

Comment: You can't. PDFBox for Android doesn't have rendering, i.e. convert a PDF page to a BufferedImage, see issues 3 and 12.